# How can i share some common page objects and cucumber step definitions between multiple projects in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, watir-webdriver

We have multiple projects that use some common step definitions and page objects in the cucumber tests. I want to not duplicate such common stuff in each projects but would prefer having a way to share these between multiple projects.

Has anyone done such a thing before?

I am using Ruby.

Comment: Sure pretty much every testing framework has a way to share methods. I am answering to be friendly but Google reveals Test Harnesses and Scenario outlines [Here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/18905-how-to-not-repeat-yourself-in-cucumber-scenarios) and [Here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines) and [More of the Same](http://pivotallabs.com/cucumber-step-definitions-are-not-methods/). Hope this helps as your question lacks many of the requested items for a question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Shared steps could be packed as gem, and included as a dependency in both projects.

For example, we have a gem named 'common', which contains common.rb:

```
When(/^I share steps$/) do
  puts "And I do!"
end

Then(/^I should be able to use it from another project$/) do
  puts "seems ok!"
end
```

Then we could create `features/step_definitions/common_steps.rb` in every dependent project, which consists of a single line:

```
require 'common'
```

Then we just use these shared steps like usual:

```
Feature: Sample
  Scenario: Sample
    When I share steps
    Then I should be able to use it from another project
```